# Show Windows Phone app demo to client

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, demo

I'm developing a windows phone 8.1 app for a client. I need to show a demo to the client but without uploading to the Store. One way to show the demo is by recording a video using screen recorders. Is there any other way that can be used to do the same.

PS **The client is not in my city. And he doesn't have a windows phone.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Maybe you could submit it to the store as a hidden app and give the customer a direct link? See [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/10/managing-hidden-apps-beta-apps-and-visibility-of-in-app-purchases-in-dev-center/)

Comment: Share the screen with Skype/Teamviewer. Create a VM in Azure and upload it there for everyone to use. Create a simple VM in azure, install the emulator and the app. It will work outside of Visual studio. Record your screen. There are a lot of options here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can send him the  xap file,which can be run on a Windows Phone or a Windows Phone Emulator. So to run it on the emulator or the phone you need the Application Deployment Tool. You can download the tool from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13890